# How to understand pointer behavior for this code snippet

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I know this code doesn't make much sense but I just wanted to know how the pointers in this code are working.

```
int main()
{
    int a=2;
    int *b = &a;
    void* c = (void*)b;
    
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d",a,&a,*b,b,c,*(int*)(c+1));
    *(int*)(c+1) = 3;
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d",a,&a,*b,b,c,*(int*)(c+1));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is given below.

```
2 -1244818996 2 -1244818996 -1244818996 -872415232                                                                                            
770 -1244818996 -1244818996 -1244819200 -1244818996 3
```

I ran this code many times, and the output for pointer values were different (obviously) but the values of a as "2" and "770" remained same for *(int*)(c+1) = 3 and changed only when i changed c+1 to c+2 or c+3, or changed "3" to some other value. So I want to know what is the link between this a=2 changing to a=770 with *(int*)(c+1) = 3, and how is it changing.

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print pointers. If you compiled with `-Wall -Wextra` (which you should) the compiler would have warned you about this.

Comment: How does `c+1` compile at all?

Comment: @Gerhardh It's a GCC extension which makes `sizeof(void) == 1` true and pointer arithmetic on `void *` behave the same as pointer arithmetic on `char *`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks. I always forgot about those extensions. Never used them... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lot of undefined behavior.

> `printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d",a,&a,*b,b,c,*(int*)(c+1));`

`a` will print 2.

`&a` will print the low `sizeof(int)` bytes of the address, as an address has 8 bytes on 64 bit PCs.

`*b` will print 2.

`b` is the same as with `&a`.

`c` is the same as `&a` and `b`.

`*(int*)(c+1)` will "construct" an int, from three bytes of `a` in memory and one byte, that is after `a`.

> `printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d",a,&a,*b,b,c,*(int*)(c+1));`

You changed a part of a, because you changed `c`, that points to some bytes of `a`, so the values change,too.

Comment: The third format specifier might not even print `*b` at all but take the remaining half of the previous address passed by `&a` that was not consumed by `%d`

Comment: Yes, it really depends on such a lot of factors, on implementation details and a lot of undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Code is very much unportable, but basically, you have a little endian machine there. I'll assume `sizeof(int) == 4` here. Another assumption is that void pointer arithmetic works same as char.

`int a = 2;` puts `0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00` at address of `a`.

Later `*(int*)(c+1) = 3;` puts `0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00` at address of `a + 1 byte`, so you get `0x02 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

Now if you interpret `a` as an int again, it's (I'm using ** for exponentiation)`2*2**0 + 3*2**8 + 0*2**16 + 0*2**24 = 2 + 3*256 = 770`.

Using a debugger and looking at raw memory might help make things clearer.